# Optimising Floating Animation in CSS

Tags: css, css-animations

### What I have done...

I am in the process of creating a 'floating' animation for a website. I have successfully created the animation but I am struggling to configure the CSS correctly to ensure the elements animate in a less 'robotic' and more realistic way...

### My Code

```css
/* Define the icons */
.icon {position:absolute;display:block;border:2px solid #000;border-radius:50%;}
.icon:nth-child(1) {width:95px;height:95px;top:10px;left:0;}
.icon:nth-child(2) {width:140px;height:140px;top:65px;left:80px;}
.icon:nth-child(3) {width:70px;height:70px;top:45px;left:218px;}

/* Define the animations for the icons */
.icon {
 animation-name: floating;
 -webkit-animation-name: floating;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.icon:nth-child(1) {animation-duration: 4s;}
.icon:nth-child(2) {animation-duration: 5s;}
.icon:nth-child(3) {animation-duration: 3s;}

@keyframes floating {
 0% {
  transform: translateY(0%); 
 }
 50% {
  transform: translateY(15%); 
 } 
 100% {
  transform: translateY(0%);
 }   
}
@-webkit-keyframes floating {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%); 
 }
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(15%); 
 } 
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
 }
}
```

```html
<i class="icon"></i>
<i class="icon"></i>
<i class="icon"></i>
```

### What I am Trying to Achieve

So, ideally I would like the three circles to 'float' in a natural and realistic way as opposed to being so robotic.

Can anyone lend some assistance with the configuration of the animation to ensure it looks more natural? I essentially want the three circles to actually look like they are floating instead of just moving up and down in a predictable manner...

Feel free to also play with the scale if this will make a difference...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;`

```css
/* Define the icons */
.icon {position:absolute;display:block;border:2px solid #000;border-radius:50%;}
.icon:nth-child(1) {width:95px;height:95px;top:10px;left:0;}
.icon:nth-child(2) {width:140px;height:140px;top:65px;left:80px;}
.icon:nth-child(3) {width:70px;height:70px;top:45px;left:218px;}

/* Define the animations for the icons */
.icon {
 animation-name: floating;
 -webkit-animation-name: floating;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
.icon:nth-child(1) {animation-duration: 4s;}
.icon:nth-child(2) {animation-duration: 5s;}
.icon:nth-child(3) {animation-duration: 3s;}

@keyframes floating {
 0% {
  transform: translate(0%,0%); 
 }
 25% {
  transform: translate(5%,15%); 
 } 
 50% {
  transform: translate(10%,5%); 
 } 
 75% {
  transform: translate(0%,15%); 
 } 
 100% {
  transform: translate(0%,0%);
 }   
}
@-webkit-keyframes floating {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%,0%); 
 }
 25% {
  -webkit-transform: translate(5%,15%); 
 } 
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: translate(10%,5%); 
 } 
 75% {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%,15%); 
 } 
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%,0%);
 }   
}
```

```html
<i class="icon"></i>
<i class="icon"></i>
<i class="icon"></i>
```

Comment: As simple as that eh... haha. Thanks very much. Would you add anything else to make them a little more realistic?

Comment: @BenCarey You can add more steps, separate intervals, etc. ... just roll up your sleeves and start play :)